# How to order string of exact format (dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm) using sparkSQL or Dataframe API

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I want a dataframe to be reordered in ascending order based on a datetime column which is in the format of **"23-07-2018 16:01"**

My program sorts to date level but not **HH:mm** standard.I want output to include HH:mm details as well sorted according to it.

```
package com.spark
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{to_date, to_timestamp}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

object conversion{

  def main(args:Array[String]) = {

    val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("conversion").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._

    val sourceDF = spark.read.format("csv").option("header","true").option("inferSchema","true").load("D:\\2018_Sheet1.csv")

    val modifiedDF = sourceDF.withColumn("CredetialEndDate",to_date($"CredetialEndDate","dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"))

    //This converts into "dd-MM-yyyy" but "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm" is expected
    //what is the equivalent Dataframe API to convert string to HH:mm ?

    modifiedDF.createOrReplaceGlobalTempView("conversion")

    val sortedDF = spark.sql("select * from global_temp.conversion order by CredetialEndDate ASC ").show(50)
    //dd-MM-YYYY 23-07-2018 16:01

  }
}
```

So my result should have the column in the format "**23-07-2018 16:01**" instead of just "**23-07-2018**" and having sorted ascending manner.

Answer (score 1):

The method to_date converts the column into a DateType which has date only, no time. Try to use to_timestamp instead.

Edit: If you want to do the sorting but keep the original string representation you can do something like:

```
val modifiedDF = sourceDF.withColumn("SortingColumn",to_timestamp($"CredetialEndDate","dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"))
```

and then modify the result to:

```
val sortedDF = spark.sql("select * from global_temp.conversion order by SortingColumnASC ").drop("SortingColumn").show(50)
```

Comment: Hi Assaf, When i use the to_timestamp function the output format was represented as "2018-01-02T04:59:00.000+05:30" where as i was expecting  "23-07-2018 16:01".

Comment: The result of to_timestamp is a timestamp not a string. Sorting by it would correctly sort by the date and time. The representation you see ("2018-01-02T04:59:00.000+05:30") is just a string representation. If you want to keep the original string representation (as opposed to keeping a timestamp column) you can change the addColumn to give it a new name (instead of overriding CredentialEndDate) and do a drop. I edited the answer to show this